# Multiple relationships to the same table with the same backref name

Tags: python-3.x, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm building a project inventory app where projects are linked together via some sort of master project. A master project have several distinct projects. I want to be able to access the corresponding master project from each project. A project can be linked to only one master project.

The application is built using Flask and SQLAlchemy and Python 3.6.5. I've tried several `back_ref` and `back_populates` tricks but I always got this error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Error creating backref 'projects' on relationship 'MasterProject.reseller_project': property of that name exists on mapper 'Mapper|Project|projects'
```

I found several other posts about this topic but the `backref`s refer always to different names. I want then to have the same name if that's possible.

Here is my code:

```py
class Project(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'projects'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)

class MasterProject(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'master_projects'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    manufacturer_pid = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('projects.id'))
    reseller_pid = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('projects.id'))
    distributor_pid = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('projects.id'))
    influencer_pid = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('projects.id'))

    manufacturer_project = db.relationship('Project', foreign_keys=[manufacturer_pid],
                                           backref='master_project')
    reseller_project = db.relationship('Project', foreign_keys=[reseller_pid],
                                       backref='master_project')
    distributor_project = db.relationship('Project', foreign_keys=[distributor_pid],
                                          backref='master_project')
    influencer_project = db.relationship('Project', foreign_keys=[influencer_pid],
                                         backref='master_project')
```

I want the following: let's say `p1` is a Project. I want to be able to access `p1.master_project`, regardless of what `p1` is in its master poject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example seems to lend itself to a [Class Inheritance Pattern](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/inheritance.html#mapping-class-inheritance-hierarchies).

Instead of having one project type, you have multiple project types that inherit from a base `Project` class. Then, the relationships backrefs from `MasterProject` can all point to the appropriate class that the relationship represents.

For example:

```py
class Project(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "projects"

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    type_ = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=False)

    __mapper_args__ = {"polymorphic_on": type_}


class ResellerProject(Project):

    __mapper_args__ = {"polymorphic_identity": "reseller"}


class ManufacturerProject(Project):

    __mapper_args__ = {"polymorphic_identity": "manufacturer"}


class DistributorProject(Project):

    __mapper_args__ = {"polymorphic_identity": "distributor"}


class InfluencerProject(Project):

    __mapper_args__ = {"polymorphic_identity": "influencer"}


class MasterProject(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "master_projects"

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    manufacturer_pid = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("projects.id"))
    reseller_pid = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("projects.id"))
    distributor_pid = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("projects.id"))
    influencer_pid = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("projects.id"))

    manufacturer_project = db.relationship(
        "ManufacturerProject",
        foreign_keys=[manufacturer_pid],
        backref="master_project",
    )
    reseller_project = db.relationship(
        "ResellerProject",
        foreign_keys=[reseller_pid],
        backref="master_project",
    )
    distributor_project = db.relationship(
        "DistributorProject",
        foreign_keys=[distributor_pid],
        backref="master_project",
    )
    influencer_project = db.relationship(
        "InfluencerProject",
        foreign_keys=[influencer_pid],
        backref="master_project",
    )
```

Here we still only have one `projects` table, but have added another column to that table which discriminates one type of project from another. Each subclass of `Project` is associated with a unique discriminator through the `"polymorphic_identity"` key in the `__mapper_args__` dict. As each is a separate type, they can each have a relationship pointing to the `MasterProject`.

Comment: Thank you very much! That's exactly what I was looking for. Works perfectly!